# How to keep the elements close to each other even if window resize in pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I am trying to implement a design in PyQt5 that looks like this,

[image]

My requirements are keep the elements in a proportion like in the above image, like the name label("Linus torvalds"), bio textbrowser a("Creator and, ..."), and the Frame conatining follower label and count also following status in a close range that will not change even if window resize.

Here is My code,

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Bio(QWidget):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Bio")

        self.centralLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.setLayout(self.centralLayout)

        self.mainFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)

        self.centralLayout.addWidget(self.mainFrame)

        self.setUpUI()
    
    def setUpUI(self):
        self.mainFrameLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.mainFrame)

        self.name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.mainFrame)
        self.name.setText("Linus torvolds")
        self.mainFrameLayout.addWidget(self.name)

        self.bio = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.mainFrame)
        self.bio.setText("Creator and, historically, the main developer of the Linux kernel")
        self.mainFrameLayout.addWidget(self.bio)

        self.followerFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.mainFrame)
        self.followerFrameLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.followerFrame)
        self.mainFrameLayout.addWidget(self.followerFrame)

        self.follower = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.followerFrame)
        self.follower.setText("Followers")
        self.followersCount = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.followerFrame)
        self.followersCount.setText("158k")
        self.following = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.followerFrame)
        self.following.setText("Following")
        self.followingCount = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.followerFrame)
        self.followingCount.setText("0")

        self.followerFrameLayout.addWidget(self.follower)
        self.followerFrameLayout.addWidget(self.followersCount)
        self.followerFrameLayout.addWidget(self.following)
        self.followerFrameLayout.addWidget(self.followingCount)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    bio = Bio()

    bio.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is my output

[image]

Here is my UI looks when the window resize

[image]

Here when i resize the window the "Followers", "158k", "Following", and "0" are moving apart i want to stay those elements close to each other like in the design, And also how to keep the text browser element I mean it taking a lot of space for just one sentence how to make it grow with respect to contents only.

**EDIT**

I have one related question to ask,
How to adjust the space between the name **label(Linus torvolds)**, **QTextBrowser(here it contains "Creator and, historically, the main.... kernel")**, and **QFrame(Here it contains the follower and following details)**. My
current output UI the QTextBrowser height is so big for the sentence "Creator and, historically, the main developer of the Linux kernel" it makes the space difference between the name "Linus torvolds" and the "Followers: 158k Following: 0" so long i want to the layout looks like in the design (The first image that posted with the question) in which the 3 section are close to each other.

Comment: Just add `self.followerFrameLayout.addStretch(1)` after adding `self.followingCount` to the layout.

Comment: @G.M. yeah it's working!,  how to fix the text browser issue it taking of space for a single sentence.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment.  Please edit your question to clarify the problem.

Comment: @G.M. I've edited my question, I hope it's clear now

Comment: I would suggest that you split this to a separate question. Otherwise it creates chaos. Remember that SO is here not only to help you, but also help others when they are looking for answers. If you merge two questions into one, nobody will be able to find it.

Comment: @ABHIJITHEA Use a QLabel instead of a QTextBrowser. It can easily be styled to look the same, if that's an issue.

Comment: @ekhumoro The contents will get changed, I mean sometime it will contain multiple sentences do i thought QTextBrowser will be good for that, that's why i used it.

Comment: @ABHIJITHEA QLabel can render html and/or multiple lines, just like QTextBrowser.

Comment: @ABHIJITHEA in any case, QTextBrowser is mostly intended for hypertextual navigation, if you don't need that feature, use QTextEdit and `setReadOnly(True)`.